# How to sync mp3 audiobook to mobi ebook on Kindle for Android?

Tags: kindle, mobi, sync, audiobooks

I installed [Kindle for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&hl=en) in my phone.

I have ebook in mobi format and mp3. The mp3 is an audiobook for the ebook.

I have put the mobi and mp3 in the Kindle folder. The ebook can read but how do I play the mp3 together and sync with the text?

Comment: What is your goal. Are you producing a multimedia book? Are you trying to do text-to-speech? Are you trying to listen to music while reading? Explain.

Comment: The mp3 is come along with the ebook. It was audible. Not music and text-to-speech. How to sync it with ebook?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have the audio match the text then you would have to create a read aloud ebook using EPUB 3.  You can learn more about this at this link

https://www.albertopettarin.it/blog/2014/08/02/how-to-create-epub-3-read-aloud-ebooks.html